# Cannot See Downloaded Pattern in Message Broker Pattern Explorer

Tags: design-patterns, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I'm new to patterns in IBM WebSphere Message Broker, though I've been a developer/designer for some time.

I've been trying to create a sample pattern from a very simple project with a single message flow. I don't have write access to the appropriate folders in the PC, so I couldn't drag and drop the plugins; so I've resorted to creating a *.patternzip file by using the "Create Pattern Archive" option. I then switched to a new, virgin workspace and tried installing the archive (through the "download" option in the Pattern Explorer view).

However I do not see the new pattern in the list of patterns in Pattern Explorer; where should I go to find it? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did understand why this issue happened; I think the download option may simply download the pattern from a web resource and does not install it.

Opening the locally saved patternzip file with the default program (mqsi pattern installer) solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1010_stewart/1010_stewart.html

Skip down to the step entitled: "Pattern user: Installing the pattern plug-ins distributed by the pattern author"

Do you still have the problem after following these instructions? If so at what point does what you see deviate from what is expected by the instructions?

Comment: I'm not using the distribution method in this page; this talks about creating a zip file out of the plugins. I'm using the newer (I believe) method of using pattern archives, as I do not have access to the folders where I'd need to drop the plugins.